# WCF - CustomBinding for signing timestamp, body and BinarySecirityToken

Tags: wcf, signing

I need to call a java/Oracle partner which has strict format requirements.

My request should look like this :
[sample request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls4eI.png)

But it actually looks like this :
[my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCeyj.png)

The BinarySecurityToken is duplicated for some reason.

My custom binding :

```
        UPLVaccinatieGegevensClient client = new UPLVaccinatieGegevensClient(GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://...."), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("...")));
        client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "...");
        client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "...");

        var vs = client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.FirstOrDefault((i) => i.GetType().Namespace == "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink");
        if (vs != null)
        {
            client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(vs);
        }
        
        client.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign;

        //UPLVaccinatieGegevensClient client = new UPLVaccinatieGegevensClient("UPLVaccinatieGegevens1");

        var request = GetRequest();
        var response = client.GetAanleverenVaccinatieGegevens(request);
    }

    private static CustomBinding GetBinding()
    {
        var messageSecurity = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement
        {
            MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10,
            InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters
            {
                InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient,
                ReferenceStyle = SecurityTokenReferenceStyle.External,
                X509ReferenceStyle = X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.RawDataKeyIdentifier,
                RequireDerivedKeys = false
            },
            RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters
            {
                InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never,
                ReferenceStyle = SecurityTokenReferenceStyle.External,
                X509ReferenceStyle = X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any,
                RequireDerivedKeys = false
            },
        };
        messageSecurity.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
        messageSecurity.IncludeTimestamp = true;
        messageSecurity.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.LaxTimestampFirst;
        messageSecurity.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;
        messageSecurity.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;

        messageSecurity.SetKeyDerivation(false);
        messageSecurity.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(messageSecurity.InitiatorTokenParameters);
        messageSecurity.LocalClientSettings.TimestampValidityDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

        HttpsTransportBindingElement elem = new HttpsTransportBindingElement { RequireClientCertificate = true };
        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(messageSecurity, new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8), elem);

        return binding;
    }
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: I don't particularly understand your needs. Do you want to use WCF to call Java web service?

Comment: Yes indeed. My header is close to the expected request but there is a duplicate BinarySecurityToken.

Comment: My idea is to implement IClientMessageInspector, and then delete a BinarySecurityToken node before sending the SOAP message.

Comment: The security header is still not available in the BeforeSendRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the extra token was being added when X509SecurityTokenParameters.InclusionMode was set to anything else than SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never on the either of InitiatorTokenParameters, RecipientTokenParameters or EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.

You can try to set the value of InclusionMode to SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never:

```
InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. KeyInfo section looks different but server accepted my request.

Comment: If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.